# Why is there no deleteLater in QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QByteArray*` pointer and I wish to delete it. I was hoping for the `deleteLater()` function which is described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) and is part of `QObject`. This is because I wish to delete the array in another thread than the one where I created it in.

Why this function does not exist on child class `QByteArray`?

Comment: Actually, `QByteArray` is not a child of `QObject` that's why the function is not present in it - QByteArray doesn't have any signals/slots and thus can't have any pending events on qt event loop - it just doesn't require this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QByteArray` doesn't inherit `QObject`, there is no `deleteLater()`, there is no thread affinity and it shouldn't really matter where you delete it, just make sure you don't end up with dangling pointers.